# keep SSH connection live in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using simple-ssh npm module for remote connection and it is working fine with below code

```
 var SSH = require('simple-ssh');

 var ssh = new SSH({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'username',
   pass: 'password'
 });
```

But the problem is when I execute a command first time it is working fine, but when I try to execute next time the process is going idle.

```
 window.setInterval(function(){
   ssh.exec('echo $PATH', {
      out: function(stdout) {
         console.log(stdout);
      }
   }).start();
 }, 1000);
```

The timer will execute it for the first time but does not work second time.

Comment: Are you confusing `setTimeout` with `setInterval`?

Comment: @robertklep Sorry sorry in my question I misplaced it. It is just typo. I was executing the code in one event, I removed that code and placed interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that calling `exec` when a previous call to it hasn't yet finished can cause issues (at least, that's what it looks like when I test your script).

Instead of using `setInterval`, use `setTimeout` and reset the connection when the `exec` has ended but before starting a new call.

This works for me:

```
setTimeout(function executeCommand() {
  ssh.exec('echo $PATH', {
    out: function(stdout) {
      console.log('S', stdout);
    },
    exit: function() {
      ssh.reset(function() {
        setTimeout(executeCommand, 1000);
      });
    }
  }).start();
}, 1000);
```